# IBM Worklight - invokeProcedure from WindowsPhone ignores timeout parameter

Tags: windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst

We are experiencing the following problem:

- **IBM Worklight 6.3.0**
- **Windows Phone 8 / 8.1**

The mobile application invokes the `WL.Client.invokeProcedure()` method by specifying a `timeout` '180000' as an option:

The call to `invokeProcedure` fails after 60 seconds and the mobile application reports the following error:

```
{"status":404, invocationContext:"null","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later."}
```

On the server side instead the Adapter continues to run and to process data without reporting any error, its execution successfully completes after a while.

Do you know if I'm missing something or if there is some tips on `invokeProcedure` specific for WindowsPhone clients?

Thanks a lot for any help/suggestion

Comment: I'm assuming this is in a hybrid application. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, correct, this is a hybrid application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem with timeout values larger than 60 seconds although it works as expected for smaller timeout values (less than 60 seconds).  Please open a PMR with IBM for obtaining a fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support!